# Connection with mongolab gives null JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mlab

This is my server.js.

```
var express          = require('express'),
    app              = express(),
    bodyParser       = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose         = require('mongoose'),
    CohortController =require('./CohortController');

var MongoURL='mongodb://username:password@ds037395.mongolab.com:37395/abc';

mongoose.connect(MongoURL,function (error) {
    if (error) 
        console.error(error);
    else
        console.log('mongo connected');
});


app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/api/cohorts',CohortController.list);
app.post('/api/cohorts',CohortController.create);

app.listen(3000,function(){ 
  console.log('Listening...');
})
```

And my CohortController.js

```
 var mongoose=require('mongoose');

 var Cohort=mongoose.model('Cohorts',new Schema({
 id:Number,
 name:String
 }));
module.exports.create=function(req,res){
var cohort=new Cohort(req.body);
cohort.save(function(err,result){
res.json(result);
 });
}

module.exports.list=
function(req,res){
  Cohort.find({},function(err,results){
   res.json(results);
 });
}
```

When I run the node server and use the URL

> localhost:3000/api/cohorts

I am getting null JSON i.e `[]` but when I connect it with the local mongodb instance I get the correct JSON.

Comment: second parameter should be instance of schema var Schema = mongoose.Schema; mongoose.model('Cohorts', new Schema({id:Number, name:String});

Comment: have you tried the above schema

Comment: yes @Venkatraman I did that only and I edited the mistake....

Comment: is that working now ?

Comment: No...actually that is not the problem..I think

Comment: check your env variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that..?

Comment: you have pass collection during your schema defintion

Comment: The name of the schema over here is same as that I made on monoglab

Answer (score 0):

Try createConnection:

```
//Connect
var db = mongoose.createConnection(MongoURL);
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

//Once connected do actions
db.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log('Connected to DB: '+MongoURL); 
});
```

And add a category sshcema or any schema you want:

```
    var category = new Schema({
        name : String,
        quantity : Number
    });

    db.categories = db.model('categories', category)
```

Comment: @Shubham fixed, and I added and example of how you will add an schema

Comment: It shows that connected  to mongodb://username:password@ds037395.mongolab.com:37395/abc.
But the json is not fetched....It keeps on loading and loading

Comment: You need teh json? Once it display its connected its because it is connected, just add the shcemas and use the db var.

Answer (score 0):

Add collection in schema.

```
var schema = new Schema({
  id:Number,
  name:String
}, { collection: 'actor' });

// or

schema.set('collection', 'actor');

// or

var collectionName = 'actor'
var M = mongoose.model('Actor', schema, collectionName)
```

Comment: what will happen if I add the collection to the schema....
There are already collections in my mongolab account

Comment: When I access the mongolab account with the shell...I get the correct output.